# Cypress - "Route" does not work after "Page Reload"

Tags: server, routes, reload, cypress

Cypress newbie here!

I am currently using routes for more code like so:

```
cy.server()
cy.route('POST', '/**/updateUserProfileData').as('myrequest')

// perform tests here

cy.reload()
// revert changes from previous tests here     <<<FAILS HERE>>>
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I found out what happened and am posting it here since I didn't find the answer anywhere else.

The application I am testing is using "Fetch"... and not "XHR"
So in the beginning, I executed this command:

```
cy.visit(url, {
        // TODO remove this hacky workaround once Cypress supports intercepting "Fetch" (2019-December currently just supports "XHR")
        // Force polyfill to use XHR instead of Fetch
        onBeforeLoad: win => win.fetch = null
    })
```

When execute:  "cy.reload()", this configuration disappears, thus the requests/responses revert back to "Fetch" instead of "XHR" as shown in the "Developer's Console -> Network tab"

[image]

================

To work around this, I simply made a custom command in Cypress (in the "command.js" file)

```
Cypress.Commands.add('refreshPage', () => {
    cy.location('href', { log: false }).then(url => {
        cy.visit(url, {
            onBeforeLoad: win => win.fetch = null
        })
    })
})
```

Which, when being called, it simply calls the "cy.visit()" command instead of reload, setting the "Fetch to XHR" option to assure we will be using "XHR".

You can call your custom commands like so:

`cy.refreshPage()`